# using adt causes android program to crash

Tags: android, eclipse

So i'm trying get a barebones abstract type working in my android app (i'm just a hobbyist, i've probably done something pretty dumb here). The following causes the program to crash (when i press meh_button):

```
    public abstract class wifiInfoSet{
        protected String bssid;
        public String getBssid(){return bssid;}
        public void setBssid(String s){bssid = s;}
    }
    ----------------------------------------------
    wifiInfoSet wifi_info;
    public wifiInfoSet getWifiInfo(wifiInfoSet winse){
        winse.setBssid("gday");
        return winse;
    }
    -----------------------------------------------
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
            TextView display;

        meh_button = (Button) findViewById (R.id.bTestGetNetInfo);

        meh_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    display.setText(wifi_info.getBssid());
                }
            });
    }
```

I just want "gday" printed to the screen, but instead the application crashes. Eclipse gives me the error "Syntax error on token "new", delete this token" if i do

```
wifiInfoSet wifi_info = new wifiInfoSet;
```

and I get no compiler errors but the application still crashes if i do

```
wifiInfoSet wifi_info = null;
```

(Eventually the oncreate method will call getWifiInfo which will use a wifimanager to get some Strings, some ints and a SupplicantState but that's neither here nor there, it just explains why my string is called bssid and why i'm not just using the String class for this.)

Logcat:

```
01-09 20:02:55.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9778): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-09 20:02:55.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9778): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-09 20:02:55.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9778):     at coach_rider.one.Coach_rider_oneActivity$3.onClick(Coach_rider_oneActivity.java:249)
01-09 20:02:55.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9778):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
01-09 20:02:55.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9778):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
01-09 20:02:55.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9778):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-09 20:02:55.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9778):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-09 20:02:55.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9778):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-09 20:02:55.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9778):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-09 20:02:55.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9778):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-09 20:02:55.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9778):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-09 20:02:55.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9778):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
01-09 20:02:55.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9778):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
01-09 20:02:55.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9778):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: If you get a crash, you need to post the logcat here.

Comment: What is `display` and where do you initialize it?

Comment: Also `wifi_info` is never initialized in your code.

Comment: I edited to include the logcat and the line that initializes display, which is a TextView. I'm not really sure how I should initialize wifi_info...

Comment: And there you go... what's at line 249 of Coach_richer_oneActivity.java? There's an object that you didn't initialize.

Comment: 249 calls wifi_info.getBssid(). Logcat shows the same error if i set wifi_info to null so: how should I initialize wifi_info?

Comment: Well, it needs to be set to a valid object, for example via `wifi_info = new wifiInfoSet().` It sounds like you're a bit new to Java, I would recommend reading up a bit on the language first before tackling a complex Android project.

Comment: wifiInfoSet wifi_info = new wifiInfoSet(); worked like a charm. Thanks everyone, especially EboMike for being so awesome and so patient with me on my first stackoverflow question!